# add_rewrite_rule() issue with parent/child/child page

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, rewrite-tag

I have a **parent/child** and another **parent/child/child** pages. I have 2 separate page templates for both pages and the following add_rewrite_rule() code in place:

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^user/dashboard/([^/]*)/?’, 'index.php?pagename=user/dashboard&profile=$matches[1]', 'top' );

add_rewrite_rule( '^user/dashboard/billing/([^/]*)/?’, 'index.php?pagename='user/dashboard/billing&profile=$matches[1]', 'top' );
```

The first one (i.e. parent/child) works fine but the 2nd one (i.e parent/child/child) is not working. Meaning when I go to the **parent/child/child** page, it is using the template of the parent/child page and not the one assigned to itself.

If I comment out the first add_rewrite_rule() line, it works as expected. Seems like the first one is overriding the 2nd one.

I have tried flushing the rewrite rules manually by going to settings > permalinks.

I have even tried to change the order of the rewriting rules i.e. I tried registering the **parent/child/child** path before **parent/child** rule and then flushed the rules manually. But that also didn't help.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could it be the order in which the rewrite rules are registered? Maybe try registering the **parent/child/child** path before **parent/child**

Comment: @LeviCole I did try that, forgot to include in the questions description but that didn't work either ):